# Writing data to sqlite xCode

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite

first of all I am from spain so sorry about my grammar. I am writing some data to a sqlite data base, here is my code:

```objc
@try {

    NSFileManager *fileMgr=[NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSString *dbPath=[[[NSBundle mainBundle]resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"capturas.sqlite"];
    BOOL succes=[fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];
    if(!succes)
    {
        NSLog(@"Cannot locate database '%@'.",dbPath);
    }
    if (!(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &dbcapturas)==SQLITE_OK)) {
        NSLog(@"An error has occured: %@",sqlite3_errmsg(dbcapturas));
    }

    //sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatement;
    NSString *asd=numero.text;
    NSString *insertStatement=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO captura(key,tecnico, fecha,provincia,municipio,latitud,longitud,altura,familia,especie,numero,comentario)Values(\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\")",asd,tecnico,fechaHora,tecnico,municipio,latitud,longitud,altura,tecnico,animal,asd,coment];
    char *error;
    if((sqlite3_exec(dbcapturas, [insertStatement UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &error))==SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"Person inserted.");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Error: %s", error);
    }
} @catch (NSException *exception) { 
    NSLog(@"fail"); 
}
@finally {

}
```

the first time I click on the save button I get:

> 2012-07-04 12:17:45.644 adasdasd[1783:f803] Person inserted.

and the second time I get :

> 2012-07-04 12:29:18.959 adasdasd[1840:f803] Error: column key is not unique

So my code should be ok but when I open the database its totally empty, any idea?

Comment: You don't show how you open/close the database...

Answer (score 2):

You have your SQLITE db file in your main bundle. All files in the main bundle are read-only. You need to copy the db to the Documents folder.

Try this out (from http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/17262-sqlite-database-works-fine-on-simulator-but-is-readonly-on-device.html):

```
- (void)createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded
{
// First, test for existence.
BOOL success;
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@\"database_name.sql\"];
success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];
// NSLog(@\"path : %@\", writableDBPath);
if (success) return;
// The writable database does not exist, so copy the default to the appropriate location.
NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@\"database_name.sql\"];
success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:writableDBPath error:&error];
if (!success)
{
NSAssert1(0, @\"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.\", [error localizedDescription]);
}
}
```