# How to use an existed database file in Xcode, read and write?

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite

I'm a bit new to Xcode and sqlite. Now I have a database file named "mydb.db", it already has some tables and datas. I put it on my mac folder and dragger it to my Xcode project under "Supporting Files".

Here is my code, but I find that I can only read from this "mydb.db", and cannot insert data to it! When I open "mydb.db" after execute my code by sqlite manager, I cannot
find the data which should be inserted!

Who can tell me how to solve this problem? Thanks a lot!

```
NSString *dbFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mydb" ofType:@"db"];
FMDatabaseQueue *queue = [FMDatabaseQueue databaseQueueWithPath:dbFilePath]

    [queue inDatabase:^(FMDatabase *db) {
        [db executeUpdate:@"INSERT INTO Focus VALUES (?,?,?)" withArgumentsInArray:@[@"100000000",@2,@2]];

    }];
```

Comment: make sure you are opening updated db only which is stored into your Xcode project under "Supporting Files".

Comment: The sqlite db must be copied to a writeable location.

Comment: “The sqlite db must be copied to a writeable location”,how to copy?and which location is a writeable location? just copy this file and paste?

Comment: Yes, the DB must be copied to writable storage.  There are easily a hundred examples of how to do this if you search for them here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By adding the sqlite db file to your Supporting Files group in Xcode, you are just adding that file to the application's bundle so that during the build process it gets packaged with all of the other resources.  Because the application can't *write* to its bundle, you must copy the sqlite database file from the bundle to a writable location, e.g.

```
#define FORCE_RECOPY_DB NO

- (void)copyDatabaseIfNeeded {
    NSFileManager *fm = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
    NSString *documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *destinationPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"pte.sqlite"];

    void (^copyDb)(void) = ^(void){
        NSString *sourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pte" ofType:@"sqlite"];
        NSAssert1(sourcePath, @"source db does not exist at path %@",sourcePath);

        NSError *copyError = nil;
        if( ![fm copyItemAtPath:sourcePath toPath:destinationPath error:&copyError] ) {
            DDLogError(@"ERROR | db could not be copied: %@", copyError);
        }
    };
    if( FORCE_RECOPY_DB && [fm fileExistsAtPath:destinationPath] ) {
        [fm removeItemAtPath:destinationPath error:NULL];
        copyDb();
    }
    else if( ![fm fileExistsAtPath:destinationPath] ) {
        DDLogInfo(@"INFO | db file needs copying");
        copyDb();
    }
}
```

Now when you wish to open the database, use the location in the documents path.

Note that you won't be able to inspect the sqlite db file in your project and expect to find the changes written from your code.  (Since your code will now be working with the copied sqlite file.)

Comment: This will get your app rejected, use a different path: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13896757/apps-must-follow-the-ios-data-storage-guidelines-or-they-will-be-rejected-in-app

Answer (score 1):

First of all learn the tutorials of IOS.

its very simple.

```
const char *sqlStatement = "insert into Userprofile (Userauth, Age, , Year) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

then use sqlite3_prepare_v2 statement to execute that sqlStatement.

Comment: Hi,I use FMDB to execute the sqlstatement, I think FMDB is similar to sqlite3_prepare_v2,right? What I confused is that after code executed, there is no right data in the mydb.db file.

Comment: try to use **FMDatabase** instead of **FMDatabaseQueue**  and  **databaseWithPath** instead of **databaseQueueWithPath**

Comment: `FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:path];
[database open];

[database beginTransaction];

NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into person(rowid,fname,lname,address) values(null,'%@','%@','%@')",fname.text,lname.text,address.text];`
This works for me...

Comment: aha, I find the answer:[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11327299/writing-data-to-sqlite-xcode?rq=1).All files in the main bundle are read-only. I need to copy the db to the Documents folder.GOT IT! Thank you also!

Comment: Yes, you seem to have found it as I was posting answer below.  Great!